# Symfony 2 Form Create user and add Group

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I want to create a form to add a user:

```
$builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                    'required' => 'required'
                ))
                ->add('middlename')
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('isActive');
```

but I want to add also one group.
I have a entity "Group" and a form "GroupType".
But how to add a choice with all my groups to select one or multiple?

I tried:

```
->add('groups', 'choice' )
```

but getting this error:

```
Notice: Object of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection could not be converted to int in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 457
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create a choice field populated with all the Group objects from the database, use an 'entity' field. To enable multiple selection (1+ choices) use the 'multiple' option. For example:

```
$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Group',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

The value of the 'property' option determines which Group field is displayed. If you need to order the objects in the choice element or display a subset of the objects, use the 'query_builder' option to load the choice using a custom query. For example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('groups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Group',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                  ->orderBy('g.name', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

See [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) in the Symfony2 documentation.

Comment: If you got an error like: `The property "groups" in class "AppBundle\Entity\User" can be defined with the methods "addGroup()", "removeGroup()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "AppBundle\Entity\Group" given.`
You must try to add Getter and setter in User class